# Sending my variable information to a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to prepend information into my list and it is working fine. On top of that, I want to send the 2 variable below (listDescription and payment) to a url too as follows :

http://mywebsite.com/public/user/spent/?amount=**listDescription**&account=**payment**

I am trying to use ajax and send the information over with the following code but it is not working and I get no response alerts either way. Can I get some help on this please. Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready( function() {     
    var listDescription;
    var payment;
        //prepending - working fine
        $('#add_list').click( function() {
            listDescription = $('#list_description').val();
            payment = $('#payment').val();

            $('.expense_list').prepend('<div>' + "\u00A3 "  + listDescription + "\t\t\t" + payment + "\t" + '</div>');


        //This is not working
        $.ajax({
            url: "htttp://mywebsite.com/public/user/spent/",
            data: {
                amount: listDescription,
                account: payment
                  },
            type: "GET",
            async:true,
            cache:false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error"); 
            }
        });



            $('#list_form')[0].reset();
            return false;                           
        });   

     });
```

Comment: listDescription is a var inside a function and therefore not available inside the $.ajax

Comment: I have pulled out the variables out of the function. Did I get your idea right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready( function() {     

    //prepending - working fine
    var listDescription = $('#list_description').val();
    var payment = $('#payment').val();
    $('#add_list').click( function() {

        $('.expense_list').prepend('<div>' + "\u00A3 "  + listDescription + "\t\t\t" + payment + "\t" + '</div>');


    //This is not working
    $.ajax({
        url: "htttp://mywebsite.com/public/user/spent/",
        data: {
            amount: listDescription,
            account: payment
              },
        type: "GET",
        async:true,
        cache:false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error"); 
        }
    });



        $('#list_form')[0].reset();
        return false;                           
    });   

 });
```

This should work :)

Comment: Doesn't work .It shows the alert saying "success" but no update happens on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

May be try to add data type JSON in your AJAX Request?

```
dataType:'json',
```

Comment: I have added the datatype and there is no diff. I have also edited the  codes such that I declare the variables outside the function. Updated code is at the question. Please help. Tnks.